# Harddrive dynamic /dev/sd* naming error

Tags: kali-linux, hard-disk, udev

I have one new and one old computer. I was installing Debian based Kali distro v.2016.2 with DVDROM onto my old computer.

During my installation, I did the partitioning, my main HDD was `/dev/sdb` instead of `/dev/sda`

Installation was errorless but bootup has gave an error

```
Gave up waiting for bootup device /dev/sda
```

and dropped me into initramfs CLI.

When I was installing it on the new computer, no error was given and everything was flawless.

What can I do for this problem?

Note : My HDD is at IDE port.

Comment: I don't know if it is still valid, but in ancient days the device naming for IDE devices followed the scheme "primary master: a, primary slave: b" etc. (see [Drive Naming](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition-Mass-Storage-Definitions-Naming-HOWTO/x99.html) Maybe your HDD is not the primary master?